# xampp control can't connect with apache and MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed Xampp 32bit in windows 7. Also change the port number of apache. But still localhost is saying "Unable to connect". Can't figure out the problem. Anyone can help please ?

Comment: Did you actually start those services?

Comment: yes i start those .... !!